# Octave: pass commands when starting the Command Line Interface?

Tags: cmd, command-line-interface, octave

I'm trying to start the Octave CLI on Windows 10 and at the same time pass the PS1 and cd commands. So I created a .bat file with:

```
C:\Octave\Octave-4.4.0\octave.vbs --no-gui
PS1('>>'}
cd C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\1
```

but it's not passing anything to Octave. Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: See: [Startup Files](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Startup-Files.html).

Comment: That helped, thanks!